# 'user' is not a registered namespace error in DJANGO

Tags: python, django

in my main project's urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .settings.base import APP_NAME
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from rest_framework import permissions
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi


urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^api/user/', include('user.urls', namespace="user")),

]
```

in user app's urls.py :

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name="user"


urlpatterns = [

    path('password_reset/', views.ResetPasswordRequestToken.as_view(), name="reset_password_request")
]
```

Route is working on local very well. But on the production, route page is opening and I post email via api page, and then I get error below:

[image: error]

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Is this only happening in production? Are you sure you are running the exact same code?

Comment: you can try with this   ------    path('api/user/', include('user.urls', name="user")),

Answer (score 1):

> **namespace** should replaced by **name**. That can solve your problem.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .settings.base import APP_NAME
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from rest_framework import permissions
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi


urlpatterns = [

   path('api/user/', include('user.urls', name="user")),

]
```